# Infinity is some number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, infinity

`alert(1/0)` alerts `Infinity` and `alert(1/-0)` alerts `-Infinity`. `alert(-1/-0)` alerts `Infinity`, as I could expect when doing some operations with *real* numbers. I can't say that infinity is a measurable value. Does javascript think it is some number?

Comment: Do you think you can divide by zero? Yes, Infinity get treated like a number: `1.7976931348623157E+10308`.

Comment: Googling "javascript infinity" would have answered this and then some https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, `Infinity` and `-Infinity` are [special values of the Number type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.5). From the ES5 spec:

> There are two other special values, called positive Infinity and negative Infinity. For brevity, these values are also referred to for expository purposes by the symbols +∞ and −∞, respectively. (Note that these two infinite Number values are produced by the program expressions `+Infinity` (or simply `Infinity`) and `-Infinity`.)

Also note that `NaN` is a value of the Number type too, despite it being an acronym for "not a number".

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript uses [IEEE-754 to represent numerical types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985); that specification includes values for [non-numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers) such as +/-Infinity and "NaN".

```javascript
(1/0) // => Infinity
typeof(Infinity) // => "number"

Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ===  Infinity // => true
Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY === -Infinity // => true
```

Arithmetic and logical operations including the infinite values should behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

From the Mozilla docs:

> The initial value of Infinity is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. **The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number including itself**. This value behaves mathematically like infinity; for example, any positive number multiplied by Infinity is Infinity, and anything divided by Infinity is 0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity